# Backbone.js detecting scroll event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a following view

```
var FullWindow = Backbone.View.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'detect_scroll');
  },

  // bind the events
  events : {
    "scroll" : "detect_scroll"
  },

  detect_scroll: function() {
    console.log('detected');
  }
});
```

and I initialize it via

```
var full_window = new FullWindow({el:$('body')});
```

But I don't think it's working.

When I change the events to

```
events : {
  "click" : "detect_scroll"
},
```

It's fine.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I don't think that the `body` element will fire a scroll event unless you explicitly give it a scrollbar by setting set its `overflow` property to `scroll` in CSS. From the jQuery docs:

> The scroll event is sent to an element when the user scrolls to a different place in the element. It applies to window objects, but also to scrollable frames and elements with the overflow CSS property set to scroll (or auto when the element's explicit height or width is less than the height or width of its contents).

Assuming that you aren't explicitly giving the `body` element a scrollbar with `overflow:scroll` and/or a fixed height, the `scroll` event you want to listen for is probably being fired by the `window` object, not the `body`.

I think the best approach here is to drop the Backbone event binding (which is really just a shorthand, and only works on events within the `view.el` element) and bind directly to the window in `initialize()`:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'detect_scroll');
    // bind to window
    $(window).scroll(this.detect_scroll);
}
```

Comment: the body does receive the scroll event.  Please reference jsfiddle in my answer.  I was wondering the same thing at first but after manipulating things with CSS I finally got a scroll bar for the body element.

Comment: by circumventing the backbone event hash as you have above you will lose your reference to 'this' when you scroll.  it will no longer be the FullWindow object.  It will be the window object.

Comment: @KyleRogers - the body does receive the `scroll` event, but only if you specify `overflow:scroll`, which the OP may not be doing. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @KyleRogers - the reference to `this` will be bound by the `_.bindAll` function - that's the point of that line. See http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bindAll

Comment: the body always receives the scroll events, however because body doesn't have a scrollbar by default the scroll bar is that of the window object, not the body.  I think some of this will depend on what browser you are using as well.

Comment: @KyleRogers - I'm sorry, but I just don't think this is the case. If I remove your CSS (http://jsfiddle.net/nrabinowitz/r3dfw/), the `scroll` handler won't fire, because the `body` never receives the event - the `window` receives it. Am I missing something here?

Comment: by removing the CSS you are now scrolling with the document.window object's scrollbar so the the body will not fire the scroll event because it doesn't have a scrollbar that is visible or being scrolled.  It's not that the body doesn't receive the scroll event, its that the scrollbar being used in your case is the window scrollbar, not the body.

Comment: Ok, I think the difference here is mostly semantic. I'll try to clarify my answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I tried @nrabinowitz' suggestion of adding $(window).scroll(this.detect_scroll) and indeed, the event is being fired. But, is this the right place to put this event handling? If not, where should "$(window).scroll()" be placed?

Comment: Backbone's default event binding happens right before initialize() is called. So when I need to bind events manually, I do it in initialize(). But there isn't a right way to do it - it's up to you.

Comment: This always freezes my page when trying to bindAll not a very good solution in my opinion, their has to be a better way to do this.

Comment: how unbind such handler properly?

Comment: @AntonEgorov - `$(window).off(this.detect_scroll)` should do it.

Answer (score 11):

I think the problem is that Backbone uses event delegation to capture events, that is it attaches listeners to the `this.$el`, and that the `scroll` event does not bubble up by definition.
So, if the `scroll` event occurs for a child (or descendant) of `this.$el`, then this event can not be observed at `this.$el`.

The reason it works for `click`, is just because `click` bubbles up.

Answer (score 2):

The scroll bars for body and window are different and you have to make sure you aren't scrolling on the window object.  Here is a jsfiddle that illustrates the issue you are probably encountering.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/keroger2k/DQuKr/1/)

I'm not for sure if you can change the 'el' to the document.window object, but I don't think that would be a good solution anyway.  I would say your best bet is to either use CSS like I've done to help you with the body element or to create a div inside the body and reference that verse the body tag.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and this is how I implemented it

```
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $('body'),
initialize: function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop()!=0 && $(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
            if (mpListModel.get('next')) {
                var res = confirm('Next page?');
                if (res==true) {
                    myView.fetch()
                }
            }
        }
    });
},
events: {},
fetch: function() {
    //fetch stuff
}
```

});
var myView = MyView();

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the scroll event never gets cleared/unregistered, which means that on every soft-reload - or whenever the page is revisited through the Backbone router - the scroll event is re-registered.

Answer (score 0):

```
afterRender: function() {
    // <div id="page-content" class="page-content"> la class qui contiens le scroll
    var $scrollable = this.$el.find('.page-content'); 
    $scrollable.scroll(function() {
           alert("event scroll ");
    });
},
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.