# how to capture the mousewheel event in a View?

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to capture the mousewheel event inside a view with:

```
events:
  "mousewheel": "doMousewheel"

doMousewheel: (e, delta) =>
  console.log e, delta
```

This does not work as delta is undefined.

Comment: See this for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634529/backbone-js-detecting-scroll-event

Answer (score 0):

According to W3.org, the mousewheel event provides a single parameter, not two. you can get the `e.wheelDelta` from the e argument.

http://www.w3.org/TR/2007/WD-DOM-Level-3-Events-20071221/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mousewheelevents

i tried to put together a sample on jsfiddle, but i have a trackpad and not a mouse with a wheel, so i don't know if this works or not: http://jsfiddle.net/derickbailey/gxeQq/

Comment: e.wheelDelta is undefined; apparently works with : e.originalEvents.wheelDelta (trackpad too). Thanks !