# Scroll event in View not firing (backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a `scroll` event in my backbone.js View. However when I scroll the screen, the `scroll` event handler does not seem to be fired. `$(windows).scroll()` works fine though. Does this mean that the `scroll` event cannot be used for Views?

**VIEW**

```
PhotoListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#photo_list',

    events: {
        'scroll': function() {
            console.log('scrolling!');
        }
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.render, this);
    },

    render: function() {
        // ...
        }, this);
        return this;
    }
});
```

Also, if I want to use `$(windows).scroll()` to handle the scroll event, in which part of the backbone.js code should I insert it? Below is where I currently place it.

**ROUTER**

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        '': 'explore'
    },

    explore: function() {
        this.photoList = new PhotoCollection();
        var self = this;
        this.photoList.fetch({
            success: function() {
                self.photoListView = new PhotoListView({ collection: self.photoList });
                self.photoListView.render();

                // Check for Scrolling
                $(window).scroll(function() {
                    self.checkScroll();
                });
            }
        });
    },

    checkScroll: function() {
        var contentOffset = $('#photo_list').offset().top;
        var contentHeight = $('#photo_list').height();
        var pageHeight = $(window).height();
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var triggerPoint = 100;

        if(contentOffset + contentHeight - scrollTop - pageHeight < triggerPoint) {

            this.photoListView.collection.requestNextPage()
                .done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            });

        }
    }

});

var app = new AppRouter();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Comment: The scroll handler will fire when you scroll the element `"#photo_list"` since it's bound on that element... is it even scrollable?

Comment: Oh the `#photo_list` element does not have a scrollbar. I guess I need to use `$(window).scroll()` in the router, as in the above code?

Comment: Yes, `$(window).scroll` is for when you scroll the window... `$(element).scroll` is for when you scroll that element

Comment: Should I place the `$(window).scroll` code and the function `checkScroll` that it calls, in the Router as it is right now, or in the `initialize` method of view `photoListView`? That way instead of doing `this.photoListView.collection.requestNextPage()` in `checkScroll` method, I can do `this.collection.requestNextPage()`

Comment: I think your solution/problem is also discussed in following [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634529/backbone-js-detecting-scroll-event)...

Comment: Thanks, it is indeed similar. Where should I place the `$(window).scroll` code, in the router or in the view whose collection I'm fetching to when `$(window).scroll` is fired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scroll handler will fire when you scroll the element `"#photo_list"` since it's bound on that element.

`$(window).scroll` is for when you scroll the window.