# How to handle scrolling event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I want to create my own affix (spying) menu, the same as in Twitter's Bootstrap. I've the following code:

```
   var Affix = Backbone.View.extend({
        el: ".afx-list",
        events: {
            "scroll" : "onScroll"
        },
        initialize: function() {
            console.log('affix initialized');
            this.render();
        },
        render: function() {

        },
        onScroll : function() {
            console.log('scrolling');
        }

    });
```

but it doesn't work. Is it possible to handle 'scrolling' event only in backbone or underscore (not using jQuery) ?

Also, I've seen this:

```
_.bindAll(this, 'checkScroll');
$(window).scroll(this.checkScroll);
```

but it uses jQuery.

Comment: Seems to work as is, at least on FF and Chrome http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/6r7xE/

Comment: But it doesn't scroll the 'scrolling' event - and this is what i want

Comment: possible duplicate of [Backbone.js detecting scroll event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634529/backbone-js-detecting-scroll-event)

Comment: it's not the same question as I remarked I wanted to know how to do it without using jQuery, which apparently is impossible.

Comment: @OskarSzura Backbone uses jQuery to handle events. If you don't want to use jQuery, you'll have to use something on [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener). If you use an [`event aggregator`](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/03/revisiting-the-backbone-event-aggregator-lessons-learned/) in your app, you would still use jQuery, but you might do something like `$(window).scroll(function() { vent.trigger('window:scroll'); })` and just use `vent.on` or in a view, `this.listenTo(vent, 'window:scroll', function() {})`