# Backbone View is not detecting the Scroll event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I have added the scroll event into the View and made the div tag scrollable still backbone is not detecting the scroll event. I have tried by window method also but did not get any success: Can any body help me for the this

**I have following View**

```
define([
    'jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'text!templates/products.html'
], function(
    $, _, Backbone, tmpl
) {
    return Backbone.View.extend({
        events: {
            "scroll": "scroll1",
        },

        scroll1: function() {
            console.log("Inside scroll function");
        }
    })
});
```

**Following is the HTML Code**

```
<div style="overflow: scroll;">
    <ul>
        <li class="list-item">1</li>
        <li class="list-item">2</li>
        <li class="list-item">3</li>
        <li class="list-item">4</li>
        <li class="list-item">5</li>
        <li class="list-item">6</li>
        <li class="list-item">7</li>
        <li class="list-item">8</li>
        <li class="list-item">9</li>
        <li class="list-item">10</li>
        <li class="list-item">11</li>
        <li class="list-item">12</li>
        <li class="list-item">13</li>
        <li class="list-item">14</li>
        <li class="list-item">15</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Backbone.js detecting scroll event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7634529/backbone-js-detecting-scroll-event)

Comment: Specifically, [the answer about the `scroll` event which does not bubble](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20452987/1218980).